# Animation renders 95% Black Frames 5% Overexposed. Tried to deactivate single layers like fog, but no luck (Updated with Render settings)

Tags: rendering

While my viewport looks fine, my rendered animation is 95% Black Frames and a few overexposed frames that do not match the camera animation, but only it's starting position.

I already tried to deactivate all particle systems and the fog as well but that did not bring any change.

Also find my settings below:

[ViewPort  (All Fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWdbJ.png)

[image: ViewPort 2, Fine as Well]

95% of all rendered frames
[image: Black Frame]
Other 5% of rendered Frames
[image: Overexposed Frame]

These are my Render Settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to supply information like: which render engine (Cycles or Eevee?), a screenshot of some of the rendering settings (Max samples, light paths, volumes),

Comment: Yes Good idea, I added it to the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the issue by myself, it had something to do with the Blender Sequencer / Video Editor. I had a workspace open with the Video Editor and a Image sequence.

The image sequence in the Video Editor had the same path as the render. That caused the issue. I deleted the sequence and now it's working.

Comment: Sometimes if I rip enough of my head hair out, curse and throw salt over my shoulder, and play with *every* property.... !